# Meteor js parse local collection document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am creating a local collection in meteor by copying a Mongo collection to MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);, but just certain fields. However, Meteor creates a whole bunch of additional deep nested fields. How do I get my data from this?

```js
{
    "collection": {
        "_docs": {
            "_map": {
                "FmXEA7cov87GzRnGs": {
                    "_id": "FmXEA7cov87GzRnGs",
                    "Value1": 1,
                    "Value2": 4,
                    "Value3": 2,
                    "etc. etc.": value
                }
            }
        },
        "_observeQueue": {
            "_tasks": [],
            "_running": false,
            "_runTimeout": null
        },
        "next_qid": 1,
        "queries": {},
        "_savedOriginals": null,
        "paused": false
    },
    "sorter": null,
    "matcher": {
        "_paths": {},
        "_hasGeoQuery": false,
        "_hasWhere": false,
        "_isSimple": true,
        "_selector": {}
    },
    "_transform": null,
    "reactive": true
}
```

I just need what's inside "FmXEA7cov87GzRnGs", which is a dynamic field.

Or, is there a better way to create a local collection without all this additional structure?

Comment: What's the actual problem? Local collections can be queried, updated, etc... just like normal collections (with the exception that you can bulk remove on the client which normal collections disallow). If you're inserting objects you can just query for them using their keys, ex: `MyCollection.findOne({"property1": value1});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the cursor returned from your `.find({})` command. You need to either hunt down a package or loop and insert client side as below as last I heard Meteor doesnt have an in house method for bulk inserts:

```
var myDocs = originalCollection.find ({});
_.each(myDocs, function(doc) { newCollection.insert(doc); })
```

You can also try drilling through and using the original npm methods below but not sure how it will like local collections, Note the fetch to get the docs as an array not a cursor:

```
newCollection.rawCollection.insert(oldCollection.find({}).fetch(), function(err, result) { console.log(err, result) });
```

Comment: no, I'm just inserting my own constructed document, like, var doc = {"property1": value1, "property2": value2}. Just one document.

Comment: Ah okay, add .fetch() to the code you are calling to look at the documents for example myLocalCollection.find({}).fetch()